# ¿Cómo obtener una fecha en formato dd-(Nombre del mes en ingles)-yy en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date, datepicker

Quiero saber como obtengo una fecha desde un input de tipo date en el formato dd-(Mes en ingles)-yy, un ejemplo seria:

```js
function handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let fechaAFormatear = event.target.datePicker.value
  // Algoritmo para formatear la fecha
  //...
  //...
  
  //...
  let fechaFormateada = fechaAFormatear
  console.log(fechaFormateada) // => algun tipo de fecha con el formato dd-(Nombre del mes en ingles)-yy, ejemplo: 29-Jun-21
}
```

```html
<form onSubmit="handleSubmit()">
  <input id="datePicker" type="date" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Esto solo es un ejemplo de como lo quiero lograr, si tienen alguna Regexp o si se puede usar  alguna clase de ayuda se los agradecería, lo que pasa es que soy nuevo en JS y estoy aprendiendo.

Comment: Podrías usar [`toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) junto con [`replaceAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) para realizar la tarea. Has algún intento y edita tu pregunta con el intento realizado, no lo haremos todo por ti. Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el código de handleSubmit usas una palabra reservada como nombre del parámetro, eso no es correcto, siquieres puedes ponerle ev (o nada porque no es imprescindible).
Una vez has leido la fecha construyes un objeto Date y la pasas a formato local, pero tu quieres una mezcla: formato español (dia/mes/año) pero nombres en inglés ('en-EN') y separados por /
Pues nada: lees el día, el año y el mes en formato ingles y luego los unes. El script del evento te queda

```js
function handleSubmit() {
event.preventDefault();
let fechaAFormatear= event.target.datePicker.value;
let fecha = new Date(fechaAFormatear);
let dia = fecha.getDate();
let year = fecha.getFullYear();
let mes = fecha.toLocaleDateString("en-EN", {month:'long'})
let fechaFormateada = dia+"/"+mes+"/"+year;
console.log(fechaFormateada);
}
```

Cierto que también podrías obtner la cadena en inglés y luego reordenar mediante expresiones regulares, pero si estás empezando esta solución es clara y sencilla de entender.

Comment: Muchas gracias, la forma de `fecha.toLocaleDateString("en-EN", {month:'long'})` no me la sabia para transformar los datos de la fecha, me resulto muy util.